# My CSS are not fill up the bottom of the webpage

Tags: html, css, background-image

My CSS background-image not fulfill the bottom of my webpage, there are still some white space on the bottom of my webpage, how can I fulfill the webpage with my background image?

```
html, body
{
height: 100%;
}

body
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background:url('semi_buffet.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position:center center ;
background-size: cover;
font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```

Comment: show us a working code so we can see the behavior ... am pretty sure there is more CSS involved

Comment: I think that is the problem about scrolling, I have some space to scroll down, after I scroll down the white space appear. But how could I cancel this scrolling I just need a page for this webpage

Comment: with this code you should have no scroll, so share your full code and we will find the issue ... I am sure you have a h1 or p at the start and a margin-collapsing issue

Comment: owhhh, guys I found out the problem the background size should be 100% 105%, this solve my current problem it extend my image so that it cover the white space!

Comment: this a hack and not a real fix ;) if you sahre your full code you will get the real fix

Comment: can you share screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

you could try,

```
object-fit:contain;
```

or,

```
object-fit:cover;
```

Comment: there is something else going on then. share full code please

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code should be working but try this:

```
body {
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1531490744426-b6fc85d35692? 
ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=d4d73c712fdb8799f077d7c2f77af115&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2467&q=80');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
```